# XLSX JS get header of column based upon address of cell

Tags: javascript, node.js, xlsx, xlsx-js

I'm using xlsx-js with nodejs, and I'm trying to read through an xlsx sheet with a calendar format. Where a 1 denotes that an activity had occurred during that day. I can loop through each row to see if it's undefined or not, but how do I loop up to detect that cell's header?

[Here's an example of the calendar format sheet that I'm trying to read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUcCj.png)

I've tried converting the sheet to json, but the json isn't helpful because it could not detect the header cell of each day that was marked.

[Sheet to json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Bi3G.png)

Code:

```
       let fileName = `example.xlsx`;

        try {
          let workbook = XLSX.readFile(`./excel/${fileName}`, {cellDates:true});
        } catch (err) {
          logger.log('error', err);
        }
        let first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
        /* Get worksheet */
        var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];
        var jsonWorksheet = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet);
        console.log(jsonWorksheet);
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you add code that you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

What I do to make it to json is :

```
var file = "D:/excel.xlsx";
const workbook = XLSX.readFile(file, { cellDates:true, cellNF:false});
const sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
var va=  XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the header values using regex and **sheet_to_formulae**:

```js
function getSheetHeaders(sheet: WorkSheet) {
    const headerRegex = new RegExp('^([A-Za-z]+)1=\'(.*)$');

    const cells = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_formulae(sheet);
    return cells.filter(item => headerRegex.test(item)).map(item => item.split("='")[1]);
}
```